# int to bool[] in c++

Tags: c++, int, boolean

What I want to do is given an argument `const int &i`, return the bits of the binary representation of `i` in the form of an array of `bool` (And back would also be great)... Does anyone know how?

Comment: ¤ `std::bitset< sizeof( int )*CHAR_BIT >( i )` makes the bits very accessible. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you *really* need it to be specifically an array of bool, I'd use an `std::bitset`:

```
std::bitset bits<32>(i);
```

You can normally treat that pretty much like an array of bool, testing, setting and flipping individual bits, etc. Of course, if you want portability to something that has a different size of int, you may want to modify it to something like:

```
#define size (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)

std::bitset bits<size>(i);
```

Comment: "`std::bitset bits<32>(i);` is a bit ungood. See my answer-as-comment. Cheers,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: refresh your browser. Was writing the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Oh. Well `#define size` is a bit ungood too, sorry. Preferentially use ALL UPPERCASE names for macros (and not for anything else). That's because macros don't respect scopes, and the name `size` can easily occur in other code, with some other intended meaning. An even better cure than the renaming could be to write e.g. `int const intSize = (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT);`. One main difference is that this definition respect scopes. And another main difference is that its name, `intSize`, is self-explanatory: it documents what it is. Cheers,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach It's looks *good* to me. It answers the question, which was not about coding conventions. But you are correct in that respect...

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: I'm pretty sure we've had this discussion before. All upper case should really be reserved for macros that take arguments and may evaluate an argument more than once. When used for all macros, it becomes the boy who cried "wolf" -- a warning that goes unheeded, because it's constantly warning when there's no real danger.

Comment: @Jerry: all uppercase is not primarily a warning. it is a means of reducing name collisions. The name `size` is *particularly* troublesome because it is used so much, including in the standard library. As an example of that, can you guess why [this code](http://codepad.org/hW2gzgQQ) does not compile? Cheers,

Comment: -1 for defining the name `size` as a macro (that's pretty dangerous advice).

Comment: @MattG: Did you remember to `#include <bitset>`?

Comment: @Matt: I'm assuming you're trying Jerry's example. Just include header `bitset`. But don't define `size` as a macro... ;-) Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Thanks for reminding me of why I don't hang around c.l.c++.m anymore.

Comment: @Jerry: Re "Thanks for reminding me of why I don't hang around c.l.c++.m anymore." No you did not use to make such trivial beginner's errors. I am guessing that you are tired. Cheers,

Comment: Doh. Thanks. Thought that came with the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As people much more experienced than me point out, doing this can lead to problems if the number is negative (what happens exactly depends on your compiler). In any case, it would be meaningless to process negative numbers this way unless you also stipulated what kind of arithmetic representation the return value would use (1s complement? 2s complement? prefix sign bit?) so this kind of approach turns out to be practically useless for negative numbers as far as I can tell.

Sorry for diverting attention from more worthy answers.

**Original**

Well, this comes to mind:

```
int i = 42; // or whatever
std::vector<bool> vec;

while(i) {
    vec.push_back(i & 1);
    i >>= 1;
}

std::reverse(vec);
```

Of course this is not an array, but it's trivial to copy the contents of the vector to an array instead if that's what you want, for example:

```
bool boolArray[] = new bool[vec.size()];
std::copy(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), boolArray);
```

Comment: Won't that be an infinite loop? `i` never changes.

Comment: @minitech `i >>= 1` means `i = i >> 1`.

Comment: Be careful if `i` is negative.

Comment: On quite a few machines, giving it a negative number will loop infinitely (or until your `vector<bool>` runs out of memory, anyway).

Comment: @cnicutar: That was edited after I commented ;) That line wasn't there before.

Comment: @minitech: I was still editing and forgot that on the initial writeup. Added immediately, but not before you commented. :)